# XML::Simple: Parsing nested hashes/array

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse an XML file. The Xml file can be found @ http://pastebin.com/fvuwbrh9.
I have saved this xml file as `packages.xml`.

**Goal**: List all the names which are surrounded by `<packagereq>` tag in the XML (I am referring the `packagereq` which fall under the `group` in the dumper output).

I wrote below script called `rpm.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = XMLin ('packages.xml');
#print Dumper ($ref);

foreach my $a ( keys %{ $ref->{group} } )
{
    if ( exists $ref->{group}->{$a}->{packagelist} )
    {
        foreach my $b ( @{ $ref->{group}->{$a}->{packagelist}->{packagereq} } )
        {
            print $b->{content}."\n";  ### <<< referring the Dumper out put
        }   
    }
}
```

Now my script goes half way throgh and prints the package names but then it gets terminated with below error:

```
Not an ARRAY reference at rpm.pl line 29.
```

After above error, the script does not process rest of the XML file and terminates.

Above error makes me believe that somewhere value of `$ref->{group}->{$a}->{packagelist}->{packagereq}` is not an ARRAY reference.

I have gone as carefuly as I can throguh the XML file (OR the Dumper output) but found that `packagereq` always points to an ARRAY reference unless and of course I overlooked something but I doubt so.

Could you provide some input on why is it complaining about `Not an ARRAY ref`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML::Simple, the most complicated XML parser to use. Add the following:

```
my $ref = XMLin ('packages.xml',
   KeyAttr    => [qw( id )],
   ForceArray => [qw( group packagereq ignoredep )],
);
```

Comment: that's it. Thank you so much. BTW, which module woud you recommend for reading XML files in perl ?

Comment: I use XML::LibXML. A bit more wordy, but no surprises. It also allows you use the most awesomely powerful XPath queries.

Comment: Well, I will give it shot right away by rewriting above script using XML::LibXML. Thanks.

Comment: `for ($root->findnodes('//packagereq')) { say $_->textContent() }`